# Sort an Arraylist using Comparator

Tags: java, collections, comparator

To print an output as {first max,first min,second max,second min,third max,third min and so on.....}

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collection;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;

  import compl.compl;

  public class Arraylist1 {


public static void main(String args[]){

    List <Integer>list= new ArrayList <Integer> ( );

 list.add(20);
 list.add(30);
 list.add(70);
 list.add(50);
 list.add(60);
 list.add(40);

  Comparator<Integer> cmp=new Comparator<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos=0;
        if(pos%2==0){
            if(o1<o2){
                return 1; 
            }
            }
           if(pos%2!=0){
            if(o1>o2){
                return -1; 
            }
            }
            pos++;  
        }
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, cmp);
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    System.out.println(list);
}


 }
}
```

Getting an error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type int

    at Arraylist1$1.compare(Arraylist1.java:51)
    at Arraylist1$1.compare(Arraylist1.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:324)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at Arraylist1.main(Arraylist1.java:67)
```

Not getting exactly why am i getting this error, i guess this cause compartor need return type,but in my case here return type cannot be specified.

Comment: Your comparator doesn't return when `o1 == o2` or when `pos % 2 != 0`.

Comment: what is the purpose of variable `pos`

Comment: i tried doing that as well  but getting same error as:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: This method must return a result of type int

Comment: @Rajith "pos" is used to call the return 1 or return -1 as it alternatively requires +1 and -1;

Comment: I'm just going to throw this out there... why do you think you want to do this with a Comparator?

Comment: using compartor helps to get that customized sorting @Joe C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom comparator `cmp` was just assigned the task to sort the `list` in descending order

```
Comparator<Integer> cmp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 < o2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, cmp);
```

> Output: 70 60 50 40 30 20

Then the method `modifyList` was called to satisfy the max and min requirements. In this, I have created another `List<Integer>` which will pick elements from the above output list and allocated them in `1st max, 1st min, 2nd max, 2nd min ... so on...` order

```
public static List<Integer> modifyList(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size());

    int i = 0, j = list.size() - 1;
    int r = 0;
    while (r < list.size()) {
        result.add(r++, list.get(i++));
        if (i < j)
            result.add(r++, list.get(j--));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Simply filling elements from front and back side to the resultant list.

[Complete program code here](http://ideone.com/gEGVKf)

> Final Output

[image]

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC, thank you for notifying me! I will try to better explain my post :)

Comment: i want to do it with the help of comapartor

Comment: if we doing it it with the help of while loop then no need of using compartor just sort using collection.sort and use while loop as you have specified

Comment: @Swati, I have made the code modular. I would appreciate if you could once again mark it as 'accepted' since the previous one was over ridden.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I have tried to make it clear :) Please let me know if this helps. I have recently got active on StackOverflow and would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: @Devendra Lattu,Don't you think it can be done only with the comparator rather then using while loop

Comment: I tried only using the comparators first. But I need to understand the internal working on the comparators. You see, the comparisons are made multiple times. Thus, the order of comparison is not assured as per my understanding.

Comment: @Devendra Lattu.order is fixed according to me as for "odd position" we need to display largest element and for even position we need to display smallest element : public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos=0;
        if(pos%2==0){
            if(o1<o2){
                return 1; 
            }
            }
           if(pos%2!=0){
            if(o1>o2){
                return -1; 
            }
            }
            pos++;  
        }
    }
};

Comment: i had wriiten above logic but getting error as need return type

Comment: I debugged and tested that logic. It was not working according to me even after resolving the compilation errors.

Comment: will you please paste the tested logic

Comment: ideone.com/gFsNqs

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot be complied. For that you have return value in all cases n comparator.

```
 if (pos % 2 == 0) {
      if (o1 < o2) {
           return 1;
      } else if (o1 > o2) {
           return -1;
      } 
      pos++;
      TODO: defie return value here
} else { TODO: define return value here }
```

important note: your variable pos will be always 0. As it is method variable and it is created every time you invoke method. If you need just to order live, you can define comparator as (in descending order)

```
return o2.compareTo(o1);
```

in asceding order

```
return o1.compareTo(o2);
```

Comment: if (pos % 2 == 0) {
      if (o1 < o2) {
           return 1;
      } else if (o1 > o2) {
           return -1;
      } 
      pos++;
      TODO: defie return value here(if it is defined here it gets overriden everytime)
} else { TODO: define return value here }(if it is defined then same error is thrown again)

Comment: @Swati did you just copy it as is without actually defining the return values?

Comment: @Swati you have to write some code instead of TODO lines

Comment: @RealSkeptic sure, thanks. I just wanted to show simpliar approach. I'll update example

Comment: i didnt copy same code just to understand what i done i kept it same while replying

Comment: @Swati replace 2 TODO libes with return 0; It should help

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is not related to comparator/collections or not even to Java.
In programming a function must return its return value for **any** input.

Your `compare` function doen't return anything for the case where `pos%2 != 0`.

Comment: Comparator<Integer> cmp=new Comparator<Integer>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int pos=0;
   if(pos%2==0){
    if(o1<o2){
     return 1; 
    }
   }
   if(pos%2!=0){
    if(o1>o2){
     return -1; 
    }
   } 
     
  pos++; 
    
    
    }
  
    
 
  
 };

Comment: need help please suggest return type

Comment: Dude, you need to understand the concept of "return value for *any* input".
In your code in the comment - again, you're not handling the case where `pos%2==0` and `!(o1<o2)`. And by handling I mean returning a return value from the `compare` function.

Comment: Comparator<Integer> cmp=new Comparator<Integer>() { @Override public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub int pos=0; if(pos%2==0){ if(o1<o2){ return 1; } } if(pos%2!=0){ if(o1>o2){ return -1; } } pos++; } };

Comment: please edit the above code according to your suggestion